# apiRTC: how to fetch previous messages in peer-to-peer chat

Tags: chat, p2p

i am using apirtc in one of our project
we are using peer-to-peer chat
but when we are not able to find api to fetch previous messages between peers

below is the link to example repository
https://github.com/apizee/ApiRTC-examples/tree/master/peertopeer_chat

Answer (score 0):

The message history is not available for all customers yet.

Please contact us directly to get guidance to enable the feature.

Regards,

Apizee Support Team